# Week ending date with Sunday being the first day of the week

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the week ending date for a list of dates. I found the below code and it works for a traditional Monday thru Sunday week but I need a Sunday thru Saturday week (Sunday being the first day of the week).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_str = '2019-06-16'
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')

start_of_week = date_obj - timedelta(days=date_obj.weekday())
end_of_week = start_of_week + timedelta(days=6)  

print(start_of_week)
print(end_of_week)
```

The above code returns:

2019-06-10 00:00:00

2019-06-16 00:00:00

and I need it to return this:

2019-06-16 00:00:00

2019-06-22 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So weekday returns 0 for Monday and 6 for Sunday. To change that to 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday do

```
start_of_week = date_obj - timedelta((date_obj.weekday() + 1) % 7)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I think in python, Sunday is the start day of a week, LOL. Code below may help you.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# this may be the func you need.
def date_start_end(date):
    """
    calc the start and end date for input date. Sunday is the start day for a week.
    :param date: any date
    :return: st: the start date(Sunday) for this week
    :return: end: the end date(Saturday) for this week
    """
    weekDate = int(date.strftime('%w'))

    st = date + timedelta(-weekDate)
    end = date + timedelta(6 - weekDate)

    return st, end

date = datetime(2019, 6, 16)

st, end = date_start_end(date)
print(st)
print(end)

>>>2019-06-16 00:00:00
>>>2019-06-22 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding in my two cents. Datetime also has an `isoweekday` method that has Monday at 1 and Sunday at 7. Similar to @Deepstop's answer but a bit shorter:

```
start_of_week = date_sample - timedelta(days=date_sample.isoweekday()%7)
```